# Reference requests and "personal philosophy"

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to ask for reference requests concerning specific arguments.

i.e I was thinking about a topic and thought such and such [does this argument exist](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32666/can-we-wake-up-from-dreams-inside-dreams).

If not that explained some of the ire I've attracted

Answer (score 4):

The community does seem to frown upon these a bit probably because they're fishing.

Maybe the bigger point is this: [you're expected to have done some serious topical research before posing a question on StackExchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

The norm is to respect answerer's time, recognizing we are not paid support, and show this by sharing the research you've done.

So you are expected to do a significant amount of research; and *only* then post your question if you still haven't found an answer, sharing your research as part of the question.

Comment: i get what you mean, but i don't ask questions that i think i can find thru google

Comment: What exactly is meant by research here? Accompanying questions with citations from commonly acknowledged authoritative sources? Or also contributing own conclusions based on them? Where on the site can I find recommendations about it? I mean, not opinions of some key users, rather I want to know initial objective standards for question quality shared by the community, if any

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90042

Comment: What could be considered a significant amount of research? Maybe in... hours? I recently asked about Descartes views on biological species. Before doing this I researched for like 2-3 hours. But it would be very well possible to read the whole corpus of Descartes, including the written conversations with his peers. So lack of time and motivation (I'm not *obsessed* with Descartes to bring myself to read anything and everything he wrote) was definitely a reason to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

'What philosophers have considered humans as gods ?' is a reasonable reference question. I did not deny this. The accompanying text I regard as integral to the question, else why include it?, and I do not see ...

'I had a thought that if a God must exist, that God ought to be ourselves. A human being is at least as terrible as the Christian God for instance (that wiped out all humanity in a flood, and other horrible events). But just like God, the human is also capable of greatness (although not to the point of performing physically impossible events). In fact, couldn't the modern world we live in right now be considered as miraculous?

Given all that, as far as I can tell, a human is the most God-like creature, at least in the material world where one can apply and develop the 5 senses (vision, smell, taste, hear, touch).'

... as other than personal opinion. '[A]s far as I can tell, a human is the most God-like creature'. What is this if it is not the expression of a personal opinion ? And I do not think it falls within 'philosophy' as the term is construed on PSE.

I have no objection to your protesting my application of what I take to be the site rules or to your appealing my decision. I left a clear opening for the question to be reinstated, viz. by the simple removal or rewording of the accompanying text.

In case you should be under any misapprehension, I am not among the 'Many people [who] do not like these questions'. I have often answered questions relating to God and religion - and without hostility to either.

I am more than willing to meet you half way. I will reinstate the question, minus the personal opinion statements. It is open to the OP, or to yourself, to re-edit the text box with whatever commentary or annotation is suitable to the site.

Yours - Geoffrey Thomas

Answer (score -1):

Re: [What philosophers have considered humans as gods?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/60094/what-philosophers-have-considered-humans-as-gods?noredirect=1#comment164212_60094)

While I agree that questions that push a personal philosophy, or are soliciting opinions, criticism and feedback on said philosophy, are quite rightly off topic, questions of the form

> Has any canonical philosopher held that **X**?

where X is a clearly expressed, understandable concept, have typically been considered on topic as long as I've been a member here.  Many people do not like these questions, but I personally think they are an important and reasonable part of our standard praxis.

Comment: As a side note I feel this SE has recently and detrimentally become over-moderated.  Closing questions and deleting answers should be a last resort, not a first one.

Comment: What are you talking about? This is one of the most weakly moderated sites I've seen! Overly broad, opinion based, and list questions remain open for ages.